# Library that will send me an email when the log file changes

Tags: server, email, logging

I'm looking for a library that will send me an email when the log file changes. Is there any?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For specific changes try http://code.google.com/p/linscripts/wiki/logmon

It's even possible to execute another command.